# Questions about circle

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, locus

I found the following problem from a book.

[image]

> Let A = (-1, 0), B = (1, 0) and k = a constant which is not equal to
>   1. C(x, y) is a variable point such that AC = kBC. Find the locus of C.

The solution provided says something like the following:-

> With the given conditions, AC = kBC means the locus of C is a circle.

Using analytic geometry to connect both sides by distance formula, I …. (finally) obtain the equation of C as

$\ (x – \dfrac {K + 1}{K - 1})^2 + y^2 = (\dfrac {K + 1}{K - 1})^2 – 1$; where $K = k^2$

The locus is indeed a circle.

My questions are:-

(1) Does a circle always have the characteristic of AC = kBC so that we can jump to the said conclusion?

(2) Can “the locus of C being a circle under the conditions that A and B are fixed points” be proved geometrically?

(3) I have tested that for some k (and probable for all k, I suspect) neither A nor B are points on the circle. Do we have special names for A and B?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circles_of_Apollonius

Comment: (1) - the question has no sense. Given a circle $\Gamma$, what $A$ and $B$ would be? (2) - yes, through the property of circular inversion. (3) - for any point $P$ sufficiently near to $A$ the ratio $\frac{PB}{PA}$ is unbounded, hence $A$ and $B$ cannot belong to their Apollonius circle with parameter $k$. In the Wikipedia article they are called "foci".

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio For (1), If I state my question more clearly as:- A and B are two given fixed points. Does it still have no sense? (2) Thankyou for the info. (3) “Foci” is also the name I have in mind. In that case, besides other conics, a circle also has (off-centered) “foci”?

Comment: For $(1)$, you should specify what is fixed and what is not. Given $\Gamma$ and $k$, for any two points $A$ and $B$, symmetric with respect to the center of $\Gamma$, such that $AB=f(k)$, we have that $PA/PB=k$ for any $P\in\Gamma$. If this is what you meant, the answer is affirmative.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Now I understand completely. The author does have the right of making such a claim, but he/she did not make any further explanation because the knowledge of Apollonius circles is assumed.